ADO - Ignoring overlapping permissions per area path
I'm setting up an ADO project where every area path is managed and worked on by seperate teams. Ideally the teams can only view and edit only their area path but allowing viewing of everything in the project is fine as well.
What I have now is that I've denied edit and viewing permission per area path for the teams that aren't working on it.
The problem is that there's a significant amount of people that are part of more than one team. Because ADO has overlapping permissions that favors "Deny", these people cannot see (or edit) any projects they're apart of. Is there a way to ignore/override it other than creating more teams?
